# Complex mysql query which join two tables and display all records

Tags: mysql, join

I have two tables: `smiles` and `messages`. I want to display all records from both tables where:

- (user who loggedin = user_id)
- user_id=Toid or user_id=Senderid from smiles and
- user_id=sender_id or user_id=receiver_id from messages

I use 'or' here because it happens that sometimes `user_id` is sender of `messages` or `smiles` and sometimes `user_id` is receiver of `messages` and `smiles` and I want to display all the records where `user_id` is in it.

I also want total count of `messages`+`smiles` for each member who sends messages or smiles to other `user_id`.

I want to display the data like below

```
sender_user_name---Message+Smiles Count---Logged_user-------message 
user_123 --------------6------------------You're Sender-----this is the last message
user_333--------------12------------------You're Receiver---this is the last message
```

Here is table structure of messages

```
conversation_id|message_id|sender_id|receiver_id|message|message_date|view_status
```

smiles structure

```
id|Toid|Senderid|smile_type|send_date|view_status
```

I tried to get all records with UNION with WHERE clause but didn't succeed. Will appreciate any help.

Messages and smiles are two different tables

Here some more clarification

how the 'messages+smiles count' is formed -> Count user_007 as a logged in user who is checking message and smiles. In his account user222 sent him 2 messages, user333 sent him 5 smiles and he himself sent 3 messages to user555. so out put will be

```
user222     2    received        Message Details

user333     5   Received         smile type

You         3  sent to user555   message details
```

Here only last message or smile will be displayed. So if user_123 sent 6 messages and 1 smiles to user_007 than count will be 7 and whichever message or smiles came last will be displayed and if user_007 send message to another user_567 than it will be displayed in second row and so on..out put structure is in question and I also include table structure..Appreciate your effort

Comment: I think I've made it easier to understand the question — I can more or less see what you're asking for — but you should probably provide some sample data and the corresponding output.  Specifically, I'm not clear how the 'messages+smiles count' is formed.  Supposing the 'logged in user ID' is `user_007`, then is the count of 6 associated with `user_123` the number of messages and smiles sent to `user_007` by `user_123`?  Are smiles independent of messages?  And is 'this is the last message' significant?  Does it mean you want the most recent message from `user_123` to `user_007`?

Comment: One possible alternative is that the 'messages+smiles count' includes messages sent by `user_007` to `user_123` as well as vice versa.  And it might be that the last message to be displayed was sent by `user_007` to `user_123` rather than vice versa.  But your question doesn't (yet) make all these details clear.  Please edit it to include the necessary information, plus sufficient data to produce a sample output (you probably want to reduce the numbers 6 and 12 to more manageable numbers such as 3 and 4).

Comment: Thanks Jonathan I've added more clarification in question.

Answer (score 0):

You would get the "message plus smiles" count by adding them up separately:

```
select (s.numsmiles + m.nummessages)
from (select count(*) as numsmiles
      from smiles s
      where $user_id in (s.toid, s.senderid)
     ) s cross join
     (select count(*) as nummessages
      from messages m
      where $user_id in (m.sender_id, m.receiver_id)
     ) m;
```

The key is that you want to count each separately and then add the values together.

EDIT:

If you want this for all users, then the best approach is to use `union all` with `group by`:

```
select userId, sum(hasSmile) as NumSmiles, sum(hasMessage) as NumMessages,
       sum(hasSmail + hasMessage) as NumSmilesAndMessages
from ((select s.toid as userId, 1 as hasSmile, 0 as hasMessage
       from smiles s
      ) union all
      (select s.senderid, 1 as hasSmile, 0 as hasMessage
       from smiles s
      ) union all
      (select m.sender_id, 0, 1
       from messages m
      ) union all
      (select m.receiver_id, 0, 1
       from messages m
      )
     ) t
group by user_id
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution. It give me total of smiles+messages received or send by logged in user (here $user_id) but it doesn't give no smiles+message by user. For example if user123 send 4 messages and if user 333 send 9 smiles to user666 and if user666 send 2 messages to user546 than I want out put as Received  user123    4 and Received user 333   9 and Sent user564    2....do I need to add group by?